# How Can I Use A MySQL Query To Supply The "Data:" Element In An SSE Event?

Tags: mysql, html, server-sent-events

This seems like such a simple task that I'm sure I'm missing something. I apologize if I'm asking a duplicate question, but I have researched for two days now and haven't found an answer.

I want to update a Now Playing: [song on air] area of a web page for a radio station so that it displays the song currently on the air. You can see the website [here](https://941lounge.com/index_rename.html).

I'm trying to do this using Server-Sent Events, and I want to get the "Data:" element by running a MySQL query.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

//Include database connection
include 'mysql_connect.inc';

//get the most recent song
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT song FROM playlist ORDER BY rec_id DESC LIMIT 1");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo "data: Now Playing: {$row[0]}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

This is my client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("server_side.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>";
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be very gratefully appreciated and, again, I'm sorry if I'm asking a question that has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "data: The server time is: ".$row['song']."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation on the flush() function in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

When a browser makes a web request, the web-server technology (in our case PHP) can send back data either as one full stream (the default behavior) or in chunks while it is processing. The flush method (including a few others) is a way of forcing data to be sent to the client while the PHP script is still executing. As flush is the last call in your PHP file, only 1 event ever takes place.

Taking that concept, if you placed your flush into a loop (please don't do this) then you could make the web request sleep for an interval then flush, and repeat over and over making many requests happen over time. However there would be no way of telling the PHP script when to stop easily, so if the user navigated away, that script would still continue to execute indefinitely. Take a few hundred visitors and soon you would have a server that is unresponsive, all because there are too many processes that are no longer attached to visitors still running in the background.

So although you can make EventSource and SSE work for your situation, it will cause you headaches in the end, all when there is a far more simple solution available and willing called AJAX. Here is some example JavaScript code that you can use to get started. Please note that this example requires that jQuery is referenced as-well in your source (though I see you already use it on the site):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    setInterval(function() {

        $.get("server_side.php", function(response) {
            $("#result").html(response + "<br />");
        });

    }, 3000);

});
```

Where 3000 is in milliseconds. So the above code makes a request to server_side.php once every 3 seconds, and updates the HTML element with an id that equals "result" with the received data.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This worked perfectly. I up-voted your response but because I'm a newbie, it didn't display the up-vote. One last question if you don't mind: It sounds like this is going to be querying the Mysql db once every three seconds. This is going to be running 24/7. Do I need to worry about so many database calls or is that fine?

Comment: Hey I am glad it worked for you, calling the db once every 3 seconds is just an example but it will be no where near as taxing as keeping processes open using SSE so you should be fine regardless. Perhaps set it to 10 or higher instead and see how it works for you.